# C#: Working with separate .exe

Tags: c#, process

I have a complex console program for data manipulation that's a pain to use.

I'm trying to create a wrapper type GUI program to facilitate ease of use.

Right now I'm opening a new thread and using Process.Start() and capturing the output.

This works great except for one issue, **how do I cancel the process on demand from the user**?

Given the fact the process is CPU intensive and can have long run times this is very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Process.Kill()` method:

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("whatever"))
{
    process.Kill();
}
```

If you don't want to kill all the instances of `whatever` then start your process using:

```
process = Process.Start("whatever");
```

Then call the `Kill` method when you want to:

```
process.Kill();
```

Comment: The OP started the process himself, why should he bother searching for it again ? If he wanted to kill a process started by another process, your answer would have been perfect though :)

Comment: Well, that was easy.

Comment: So it worked for what you wanted? One thing though, if there are multiple instances of 'whatever' process it will kill **all** of them.

Comment: this is not a good idea to find and stop all the process of this name, user might want to keep some other instance

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have start a process like below

```
Process myProcess = Process.Start("myapp.exe");
```

then you can close the process for free up the resource

```
myProcess.Close();
```

then stop the process using

```
myProcess.Kill();
```